# Filter Pandas dataframe based on combination of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as,

```py
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  4  2
3  4  3
```

I want to filter the dataframe such that I get the result as,

```py
   a  b
0  1  2
3  4  3
```

i.e, I want the combination `(1,2)` and `(4,3)` by filtering the two columns together.

If I try this,

```py
df1 = df[df['a'].isin([1,4]) & df['b'].isin([2,3])]
```

I get the entire dataframe back because combinations of `(1,3)` and `(4,2)` also gets included in the above method. But I need only the given combinations. I have a huge list of tuples of two columns based on which I want to filter the dataframe considering the corresponding tuple combination.

Also, I dont want to merge the two columns together as a single string and then filter.

Comment: So, you only want (1,2) and (4,3) and rest all combinations should be deleted? right?

Comment: @cph_sto Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: So, you want (1,3), (2,3) etc to be deleted .....

Comment: Yes. Specifically I have a list of tuples `[(1,2), (4,3)]` and I want all the records in dataframe that match the tuple combination in this list.

Comment: Try this - `df[((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] ==2)) | ((df['a'] == 4) & (df['b'] ==3))]`, where `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4,4],'b':[2,3,2,3]})`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use -

```
df[df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin([(1,2), (4,3)])]
```

**Output**

```
    a   b
0   1   2
3   4   3
```

**Explanation**

`df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1)` gives a series of tuples -

```
0    (1, 2)
1    (2, 3)
2    (4, 2)
3    (4, 3)
```

`.isin([(1,2), (4,3)])` searches for the desired tuples and gives a boolean series

Answer (score 11):

The tuple comparison approach as outlined by [@Vivek Kalyanarangan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945974/13879777) is the way to go but the speed can be significantly increased in case of large dataframes by utilizing the MultiIndex instead of using an apply function for tuple creation:

For example, in your case:

```
keep_tuples = [(1,2), (4,3)]
tuples_in_df = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[["a","b"]])
df[tuples_in_df.isin(keep_tuples)]
```

This leads to ~5X speed improvement on a 1,000,000 X 2 sized df when compared to using apply function.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to join the two columns (`a` and `b`) as strings, and check for `12` and `43`, i.e.

```
df[df.astype(str).sum(axis = 1).isin([12, 43])]
#   a  b
#0  1  2
#3  4  3
```